# How to sell bitcoins for cash?

Tags: sell-bitcoins, cash

If I want to sell bitcoins, assuming I was successful in either buying them or selling a service or a product and accepting bitcoins instead of normal cash. How can I convert the bitcoins back to cash ?

Comment: The first obvious question to ask in response to that is to what currency would you like to convert it to?

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17239/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/32731/5406

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use an exchange which can withdrawal USD/EUR (depending what you want). A good option for that is [Kraken](http://www.kraken.com), as they have very low withdrawal and trading fees. You can trade your bitcoins to USD/EUR, and then withdrawal to your bank account. And no, I am in no way associated with Kraken, just a happy customer there

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

I'm aware of two:

In person you can use [localbitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/)

Via bank account, I think there are several companies providing that service, one of them is [Coinbase](http://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/1148716-how-do-i-buy-and-sell-bitcoin-with-a-bank-account-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of useful websites available on the internet having the below-mentioned common procedure:
Make a decision regarding the third-party broker exchange you want to employ.
Become a member and finish the verification process with the brokerage.
Put money (or bitcoin) into your account.
By transferring your bitcoin to a bank account or PayPal account, you can cash it out.