# Sell bitcoin for 0% fee

Tags: sell-bitcoins

is there any site where you can buy/sell bitcoins with 0 fee.
I know sites like ultrachange.biz and other sites but they take too much.

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a free lunch...

Comment: What fee are you referring to: the miners fee or the brokers fee?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17239/5406

Answer (score 1):

The 0-fee sites are all Chinese. btcc.com, huobi.com and okcoin.com are three prominent ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are some free websites available over the internet such as Bybit, Binance, Phemex, but I don’t know whether they are trustworthy or not, you must ensure the authority of the website before dealing in transactions.