# Where can I exchange Bitcoin for Cash, Western Union or MoneyGram?

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins

I'm looking for a Website that allows to exchange Bitcoin for Cash, Western Union or MoneyGram.

I have heard about localbitcoin.com, but people complain about spamming...

I've also heard about cryptonit.net, but they have a 20% fee which seems exorbitant.

Comment: This question could be improved by adding information about the country the asker is located in.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17239/5406

Answer (score 0):

Some bitcoin wallets allow you to link them to a checking or savings account. You could also just exchange the bitcoin onto paypal.

Comment: example please...

Comment: copay worked for me.