# How to withdraw cash from blockchain wallet

Tags: blockchain-wallet-app

Is exchanging bitcoins with money from other people the only way I can withdraw my money into my bank account??if there is another way please lead me

Answer (score 4):

> Is exchanging bitcoins with money from other people the only way I can withdraw my money into my bank account??

Yes, it's the only way.  You can't "withdraw" bitcoins into your bank account, any more than you could "withdraw" a car into your bank account.  You have to sell them in exchange for money, and then you can deposit the money in your bank account.

See [How can I sell bitcoins and transfer the funds to my bank account?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17239/how-can-i-sell-bitcoins-and-transfer-the-funds-to-my-bank-account)

Answer (score 0):

You can exchange bitcoins for dollars at the crypto-exchange. Select it depending on the commission that suits you.