# How to Back-up and Withdraw Bitcoins to My Mastercard

Tags: transactions, wallet, withdrawal

Please help me. I am new to bitcoin wallet and I would like to know how to back up my wallet and how to withdraw bitcoins to my mastercard or debit card.

Comment: Which wallet? Bitcoin-core, Electrum, Mycelium, Exodus, Bread, Wasabi, ...

Comment: Hi Bubbly, it sounds like you're asking about two distinct topics. 1) How to create a backup of your wallet, 2) How to sell bitcoins and receive the revenue to your bank account. For the former, as RedGrittyBrick indicated, we would need to know what software you are using, the latter may be a duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17239/5406. Generally, our site works best if each question only inquires about one topic, though.