# Transfer and account

Tags: transactions, exchanges

I'm attempting to clarify a few things in my mind. The wallet.dat file contains (amongst other things) my transaction history alongside the private keys associated with each address in use in the wallet.

Comment: Im wanting to know how to cash out or transfer mbtc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sell bitcoins and transfer the funds to my bank account?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17239/how-can-i-sell-bitcoins-and-transfer-the-funds-to-my-bank-account)