# Transferring Bitcoin to a bank checking account

Tags: sell-bitcoins

What app or website do I use to transfer my Bitcoin to my bank account? My Bitcoin is currently in coinbase wallet. Please help. What are the steps? I am having trouble finding the right menus to use to even add my bank let alone make a transfer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer funds to a bank account](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17239/13866). For exact current details, contact Coinbase.